# svn commit help ubuntu

Tags: svn, ubuntu

When I type in `svn commit file.h`, I get a screen which has:

```
--This line and those below will be ignored-- 
A file.h
```

And a list of `^G`, `^O`, etc. below. I would like to know how to go ahead and commit the file into the repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That screen allows you to enter a commit message. Describe what's changed in `file.h`, and then save and exit your editor (it sounds like you're using `nano` as your editor, in which case you'd hit `Ctrl-X`). Once you enter a commit message and save it, your changes will be committed to the repository.